# Partially Paid by US entity under B1/B2 Visa or Visa waiver. Is it legal?

Tags: united-states, european-union, visa, compensation

My EU employer is an affiliate company of a US company. 
Whenever the EU company’s employees are required to travel to US (under B1/B2 visa or a Visa waiver program) for some meetings with some US clients (up to 3 days each time, and up to 6 times annually), the EU company pays their regular monthly salary. 
They are additionally paid a standard per diem amount (or compensated exactly to what they have spent in US with receipts) and an additional compensation (as a bonus) that corresponds to the number of days spent overseas (US mainly).

The per diem and the additional bonus compensation is paid directly from the US company (affiliated with the EU company), as every individual EU employee (of the Eu company) has signed a separate contract (as a contractor) with the US entity. So several days later after they return, an overseas (from US to EU) transaction takes place.

I am really worried that the way the additional bonus compensation (for overseas travelling) is paid violates the terms of the B1/B2 VISA (or Visa waiver program) whenever travel to US takes place. 
Is there a real issue here?

Just to add that this applies to some employees of the EU company (as it depends on the negotiations on hiring).